# How to put a hidden fields in a formset and instantiate this value?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, formsets

I wish I could remove the user from my formset and it instantiates the value "logged_user" which is the user logged ...
How can I do to instantiate the value of a field?

I have this views.py :

```
def access(request, instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, fields=('question', 'answer', 'user'), extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Reply.objects.none())
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baseVisite/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Le formulaire est incorrecte !')
            return render_to_response('polls/error.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
     'formset': formset,
     'questions':questions,
     'logged_user':logged_user,
     'numPages' : numPages
     })
```

and this forms.py :

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        fields = ('question','answer','user')
```

my template :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <br>{{ formset.as_table }}<br>

    </table><br>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

EDIT :

```
def get_logged_user_from_request(request):
    if 'logged_user_id' in request.session:
        logged_user_id = request.session['logged_user_id']
        # On cherche un étudiant ici
        if len(Etudiant.objects.filter(id=logged_user_id)) == 1:
            return Etudiant.objects.get(id=logged_user_id)
        # On cherche un Employe ici
        elif len(Employe.objects.filter(id=logged_user_id)) == 1:
            return Employe.objects.get(id=logged_user_id)
        # Si on trouve rien -->
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None
```

**I find myself with multiple form where I can choose the user off I would like the user to define what the person is connected "logged_user"**

Comment: Note that you have defined a model form `ReplyForm`, but you are not using it in your formset. You can pass it to `modelformset_factory` if you want `ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)`. However, the model form probably isn't necessary in this case, because all you are changing is `fields`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the user from the list of fields,

```
ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, fields=('question', 'answer'), extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)
```

then set it when you are saving the formset.

```
if request.method == 'POST':  
    formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    if formset.is_valid():
        new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for new_instance in new_instances:
            new_instance.user = logged_user
            new_instance.save()
```

Comment: request.user refers to what?

Comment: In Django, `request.user` is the logged in user. Maybe you want `logged_user` in your case. I'm not sure what `get_logged_user_from_request` does. You might be able to delete that method and use `request.user`.

Comment: i can share the def get_looged_user_from request

Comment: I have this error with your code : `'ReplyForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`

Comment: The code was missing `if formset.is_valid():`, I've added it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103297/discussion-between-jeremy-lgdr-and-alasdair).

Comment: It looks like `get_logged_user_from_request` can return an `Etudiant` or an `Employe`. That means that setting `new_instance.user = new_instance.logged_user` won't work - you need to use the same model that the `Reply.user` foreign key points to. You should think about using the built in Django auth, instead of using your own, but that's off topic for this question.

Comment: I have an other question in the same way 
I now instantiate the fields questions with this filter -> Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
That would allow me to answer that question that interested me in terms of "Instance"
I wish I could complete a self fields, is it possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If your initial problem is solved, it would be better to ask a new question instead of commenting here.